# Electronjs require usage on renderer process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In electron app, we can require node modules in both renderer and main process. I've realized when I require a module in renderer process' main (html's entry script) it becomes available throughout every file I have. I might not have explained it very clearly so let me give an example.

Consider the following layout for the electron project:

```
src\
main.js
module1.js
module2.js
index.js
index.html
```

main.js is the main process of the electron app and index.js is a script loaded inside index.html at the end of its body tag.

Inside index.js I require both module1 and module2 (rest of the file is irrelevant)

```
const m1 = require('module1')
const m2 = require('module2')
```

what I realized here is that, inside the module2 I have access to m1 variable now. So I don't need to require module1 again inside the module2 if I need it.

module2:

```
console.log(m1) // actually shows the m1 that was required in index.js
```

I feel like I made a mistake trying to write renderer side as if it was a node application. And I failed to find any documentation regarding the general rules while writing the renderer side of the electron app. I know this is a bit indirect question but could you guide me regarding the renderer process layout. Shouldn't I try to separate renderer js file into modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of preload argument in webPreferences while creating the main BrowserWindow.

OR

Try using the remote module of electron (https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)

OR

Access the module in main process, call the functions for the expected outcome and send back the result to the renderer process using IPC.